# Using ramda to modify a property in array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I am trying to remove some properties from an array of objects using `ramda`. I have an array of properties to remove like:

```
const colToHide = ['name', 'age']; 
// those properties are selected by the user
```

And I want to remove the properties `'name'` and `'age'` (or any user selected property) from one array of objects. The array of objects is something like this:

```
const person = [
  {name:'sam', age:'24', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true},
  {name:'john', age:'25', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true}
];
```

What would be right way to update that array of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.omit()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#omit) method in conjunction with a  [.map()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map). Something like this:

```js
const person = [
  {name:'sam', age:'24', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true},
  {name:'john', age:'25', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true}
]

const omitKeys = (keys, arr) => R.map(R.omit(keys), arr);

console.log(omitKeys(["name", "age"], person));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Even more, you can use [.compose()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) as @ScottSauyet proposed on the comments to do:

```
const omitKeys = R.compose(R.map, R.omit);
```

And then use it as:

```
omitKeys(["name", "age"])(person);
```

```js
const person = [
  {name:'sam', age:'24', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true},
  {name:'john', age:'25', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true}
]

const omitKeys = R.compose(R.map, R.omit);

console.log(omitKeys(["name", "age"])(person));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And if you don't mind calling it like `omit (keys) (xs)`, then this can be simplified to `const omitKeys = compose (map, omit)`.  You need something like the above (or Hitmand's `useWith` solution) to the the `omit (keys, xs)` API.

Answer (score 2):

or in a point free style using `R.useWith`:

```js
const omit = R.useWith(R.map, [
  R.omit, 
  R.identity,
]);

const persons = [
  {name:'sam', age:'24', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true},
  {name:'john', age:'25', address:'xyz avenue', employed:true}
]

console.log(
  'result',
  omit(["name", "age"], persons),
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```